# Which substitution do I use?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

For $x>0$, let $f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t-x^2/t} t^{-1/2}dt$.
a) show that $f(x)=x\int_0^\infty e^{-t-x^2/t} t^{-3/2}dt$ via an adequate substitution.
b) Calculate $f'(x)$ and show that $f(x)=Ce^{-2x}$ for some constant $C$ (no need to evaluate $C$).

I tried some substitutions but none worked, so I hadn't even tried the second part.

Comment: Hint: Gamma Function...?

Comment: Are you sure that it **must** be substitution ?

Answer (score 1):

We define $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by

$$f(x):=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}} \frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}.$$

For part a), use the substitution $u=\frac{x^2}{t} \iff t=\frac{x^2}{u}$. Then

$$t+\frac{x^2}{t}=\frac{x^2}{u}+u,\\
\sqrt{u}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}=\frac{\sqrt{u}}{x},\\
dt = -\frac{x^2}{u^2}du\implies \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}=-\frac{x}{u^{3/2}}du,$$

and so,

$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}} \frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}\\
=-\int_{\infty}^{0}e^{-u-\frac{x^2}{u}} \frac{x}{u^{3/2}}du\\
=x\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u-\frac{x^2}{u}} \frac{du}{u^{3/2}}\\
=x\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}} \frac{dt}{t^{3/2}},$$

as was to be demonstrated.

For part b), differentiate under the integral sign:

$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}} \frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}\\
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}} \frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}\\
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-2x}{t}\right)e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}} \frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}\\
=-2x\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t-\frac{x^2}{t}} \frac{dt}{t^{3/2}}\\
=-2f(x),$$

where in the last line we've made use of the identity proven in part a). So since $f(x)$ satisfies the 1st-order linear ODE $f^\prime+2f=0$, we must have

$$f(x)=Ce^{-2x},$$

for some constant $C$, as was to be demonstrated.

---

Optional: To find $C$, note that $f(x)=Ce^{-2x}\implies f(0)=C$. Then going back to the original definition of $f(x)$,

$$f(0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{|x|}\,2x\,dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}.$$

Hence,

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2x}.$$